# MySQL username variable carried over to another file

Tags: mysql, variables

So I just set this up:
http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/6.html

It was fairly easy, now I have it redirecting to another page but how can I pull the successful username used?

I'm trying to build a basic chat program to learn with.

Getting this would solve how I will add the variable when a message is sent off to the mysql database and to verify it was sent by the right person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for what we commonly call `SESSION variables`.  This type of variable offers persistence over different pages. The api for handling sessions is nice and simple, and in my (personal opinion) session variables can be ***very*** handy, and dead simple to put in action.
Especially for tasks like the one you have at hand, keeping messages and usernames and such. You can even pass objects in sessions, if you want to get wild, just serialise and deserialise the data  before and after saving it in a $_SESSION var.

Read up the  [session handling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php) section in php, this should give you a hint on how to tackle your problem.

On a sidenote, though, there are other ways that don't need session variables, since you posted php code I assumed you wanted a php related answer.

Good-luck